# vector of Base unique_ptr to derive

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

I am trying below code to create a vector of Base class and dynamically allocate of derived class.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

class Base {

public:
  Base(int value) : item(value) {}
  int item;
};

class Derived : public Base {

public:
  Derived() : Base(0) {}
};

class Fac {
public:
  int count;
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> m_BaseObj;

  void add(int data) {
    count++;
    m_BaseObj.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Base>(new Derived()));
    int index = (m_BaseObj.size() - 1);
    std::cout << "Index=" << index << std::endl;
    m_BaseObj[index].get()->item = data;
  }

  void display() {
    for (auto &Obj : m_BaseObj) {
      std::cout << Obj.get()->item << "  ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
  void deleteList() {
    int it;
    std::cout << "Enter item to delete:";
    std::cin >> it;
    int index = 0;
    m_BaseObj.erase(std::remove_if(m_BaseObj.begin(), m_BaseObj.end(),
                                   [it](const std::unique_ptr<Derived> &e) {
                                     return it == e->item;
                                   }),
                    m_BaseObj.end());
  }
};

int main() {
  Fac obj;
  int ch;
  obj.count = 0;
  while (1) {
    std::cout << "1. Add  2. Remove 3. Display\n";
    std::cin >> ch;
    switch (ch) {
    case 1:
      int data;
      std::cout << "Data: ";
      std::cin >> data;
      obj.add(data);
      obj.display();
      break;
    case 2:
      obj.deleteList();
      obj.display();
      break;
    case 3:
      obj.display();
      break;
    default:
      std::cout << "Invalid choice\n";
      exit(0);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the compile error while allocating for derive class. If I create for Derive than the code seems to work correctly.

```
    In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/algorithm:62:0,
                 from vector.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of â_FIter std::remove_if(_FIter, _FIter, _Predicate) [with _FIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::unique_ptr<Base>*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base> > >; _Predicate = Fac::deleteList()::__lambda0]â:
vector.cpp:53:64:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:1150:33: error: no match for call to â(Fac::deleteList()::__lambda0) (std::unique_ptr<Base>&)â
         if(!bool(__pred(*__first)))
                                 ^
vector.cpp:52:48: note: candidate is:
         m_BaseObj.begin(), m_BaseObj.end(), [it](const std::unique_ptr<Derived>& e)
                                                ^
vector.cpp:52:83: note: Fac::deleteList()::__lambda0
         m_BaseObj.begin(), m_BaseObj.end(), [it](const std::unique_ptr<Derived>& e)
```

Comment: On a side note, all of you calls to `unique_ptr.get()->` can be replaced with `unique_ptr->`, eg: `m_BaseObj[index].get()->item` should be `m_BaseObj[index]->item`, `Obj.get()->item` should be `Obj->item `, etc. `std::unique_ptr` overrides `operator->` for this purpose.

Comment: Also, don't forget to add a virtual destructor to `Base` or else derived classes will not be destructed correctly when `unique_ptr` calls `delete` on its `Base*` pointer. Not so important in your particular example, but it is important if a derived class has any data members that require destruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your predicate to `remove_if` needs to accept pointer to `Base`, not `Derived`.  You can do the casting within it.

Compiler error is actually pretty clear.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 2):

`std::remove_if` needs to pass the element type which is `std::unique_ptr<Base>` to its predicate.  But the predicate lambda you've supplied expects a `const std::unique_ptr<Derived>&` argument.  These are different types, and `unique_ptr<Base>` is not convertible to `unique_ptr<Derived>`.

Fix your lambda to take `const std::unique_ptr<Base>&` as an argument.

Comment: And if you think about it, you will see why `std::unique_ptr<Base>` is not convertible to `std::unique_ptr<Derived>`. Think of what would happen if you had multiple derived classes stored in the same `std::vector`. The `std::remove_if()` predicate could not accept a `std::unique<Derived>` because it might be passed a `std::unique_ptr<SomethingElse>` instead. So it can only accept a `std::unique_ptr<Base>`, and then the predicate has to use other means to determine whether the `Base` is really a `Derived` or a `SomethingElse`.